# Checking the a section $\sigma$ of a vector bundle $f:E\to M$ is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I have a clarifying question about sections of vector bundles. Let $\pi:E\to M$ be a smooth vector bundle of rank $n$, and $\sigma:M\to E$ be some map. I want to show that $\sigma$ is a section of $E$.

First, I want to show that $(\pi\circ\sigma)(p)=p$ for all $p\in M$.

Second, I want to show that $\sigma$ is a smooth map. Since $E$ is a smooth vector bundle over $M$ of rank $n$, then there exists an open cover $\{U_i\}$ of $M$ s.t. for all i, there is a diffeomorphism
$$\varphi_i:\pi^{-1}(U_i)\to U_i\times\mathbb{R}^n$$
So, in order to show that $\sigma$ is smooth, I want to show that $\sigma|_{U_i}$ is smooth for all $i$ where
$$\sigma|_{U_i}:=\varphi_i\circ\sigma:U_i\to U_i\times\mathbb{R}^n.$$
To show that $\sigma|_{U_i}$ is smooth, it's enough to show that $\sigma|_{U_i}$ is smooth on open charts of $M$ i.e.
$$(\psi_i\times id)\circ \sigma|_{U_i}\circ \psi_i^{-1}:\hat{U_i}\to \hat{U_i}\times\mathbb{R}^n\text{ is smooth for all }i$$
where, assuming that $\dim(M)=k$, $\psi_i:U\to \hat{U}\subset \mathbb{R}^k$ is a homeomorphism. If the original $U_i$ is big enough, we always can make it smaller to obtain $\psi_i$.

**For example:**

Consider a tangent bundle of a circle, i.e. $TS^1$, and a map $\sigma:S^1\to TS^1$ where $\sigma(\theta)=(\theta,\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta})$. So, if I want to show that $\sigma$ is a smooth section, then I need to choose an open cover of $S^1$ which will give me a local trivialization of a tangent bundle and write that map in local coordinates.

But, we can use another approach where I will start with some opens $U_i\times\mathbb{R}$ and smooth maps $g_{ij}:U_{i}\cap U_j\to GL(\mathbb{R})$, i.e. so I can use them to glue my tangent bundle. Then if we know each
$$s_i:U_i\to U_i\times\mathbb{R}$$
where $s_i(p)=(p,\phi_i(p))$ and that $\phi_j(p)=g_{ij}(p)\phi_i(p)$, then it's enough to check that each $s_i$ is smooth map to obtain that $s$, as a section over tangent bundle, is smooth.

So, my question is basically comparing this two approaches and a general idea how to show that some map is a section.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly are you asking because you seemed to understand the construction well. If you want to see why these two ways of defining sections are equivalent, you should start by looking at the corresponding two equivalent definitions of vector bundles.

Comment: @lEm, oh, I just want to confirm that I understand it correctly. Thank you!